# WildFly10 installation - cannot create user

Tags: jboss, wildfly-10

I have a problem with installing WildFly10. In youtube tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HUFaL--SwI) at 8:39 I cannot see "Terminate batch job Y/N?".

If I go to http://localhost:8080/ I can see that my server is running.

My cmd:

```
C:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\bin>standalone
Calling "C:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
Setting JAVA property to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java"
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: "C:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final"

  JAVA: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java"

  JAVA_OPTS: "-Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman"

===============================================================================

10:28:47,503 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.2.Final
10:28:47,692 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final

*
*
a lot of text
*
*

10:28:49,980 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) started in 2758ms - Started 331 of 577 services (393 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

So, what should I do to finish tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in youtube link, you need to press `Ctrl+c` to shutdown server. This will ask you "Terminate batch job Y/N?".

However you can add user without shutting down server.